# analytic set is the union of a Borel and a negligible set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a Polish space, $\mu$ is a Radon probability measure on $X$. $\mathcal{A}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of the analytic sets. Then for any $A \in \mathcal{A}$, there is a $\mu$-negligible set $S$ such that $A\backslash S$ is a Borel subset?